# Is there such a thing as a $0^\circ$ angle?

Tags: angle

I am curious if there is such a thing as a zero degree angle, and if so, what does it look like? I am also wondering if a zero degree angle equals a $360^\circ$ degree angle? I understand that a $360^\circ$ angle is essentially a circle, or the amount of "turn" that equals a circle. I am pondering how you would draw a $360^\circ$ angle. Would it be drawn like ___________ (or just a straight line)?

Comment: Yes, there is, it is even [marked on the protractor](http://www.mathplanet.com/education/geometry/points,-lines,-planes-and-angles/measure-and-classify-an-angle), it looks like a double half-line. It is not exactly "the same" as 360 degree angle, although it is the same double half-line, but for 0 you take the non-space between the doubles to be the angle, and for 360 the full circle on the outside of them.

Comment: A related question: what is the precise definition of an "angle"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider two rays that form some angle greater than zero degrees. Then picture one of the rays rotating toward the other ray until they both lie in the same line. The angle they create has been shrunk from its original measure to zero degrees. The angle that is now formed has a measure of zero degrees.[image] $$\text { A zero degree angle} $$

---

See [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20171122112913/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/64382.html) and also this [MSE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1741388/do-zero-degree-angles-exist). Hope it helps.

Answer (score 6):

A $0$ degree angle is "co-terminal" with a $360$ degree angle, but they are not equal.  But when you draw them, they look the same, and yes, it's just a (half of) a straight line.

Comment: +1 for being the only one so far to use the word coterminal.

Comment: Just some trivia: a half-straight-line is called a ray.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, $0^\circ$ angle exist and both $360^\circ$ and $0^\circ$ are different. Since both are reverse of each other, since their sum is $360^\circ$. Consider the case non-touching parallel lines, the angle between them is $0^\circ$ since they could [never meet on a point.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2071307/does-parallel-lines-meet-at-two-points/2071326#2071326)